# Unable to remove faulted Node using Remove-ServiceFabricNodeState any more

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-cli, azure-rm, azure-cloud-shell

I used to use `Remove-ServiceFabricNodeState` to remove faulted Service Fabric nodes. with this cmdlet i was able to remove a specific node by its name.

However I'm unable to use this cmdlet any more. It is not allowing me to install the module using Install-Module ServiceFabric anymore saying the module cannot be found in the gallery.

Also I'm unable to find a similar cmdlet in iether Az.ServiceFabric or az cli. all that is available is a `Remove-AzServiceFabricNode` which cannot specify which node I want to remove. It just accepts an integer for how many nodes I want to remove.

I would like to know how can I remove a Node by its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `Remove-ServiceFabricNodeState`, just need to install the [Azure Service Fabric SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started#sdk-installation-only), it also includes the runtime and tools, after installing it, reopen a PowerShell session, you will be able to use the command.

[image]

Besides, you can also use the [Azure Service Fabric CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cli) command [`sfctl node remove-state`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-sfctl-node#sfctl-node-remove-state) as mentioned in another reply, all depend on your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Azure Service Fabric CLI** with

`sfctl node remove-state --node-name Node01 --timeout 60`

This will remove the state of Node1 with a timeout of 60 seconds. [Documnetation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-sfctl-node#sfctl-node-remove-state)

For more information on how to install sfctl see [how to install sfctl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cli)
Simple version:

1. Install Python (Version 3.X)
2. Install Pip
3. Execute the following command `pip install -I sfctl==9.0.0`. See [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cli#service-fabric-target-runtime) to see which version you need.